# How to modify a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Given the identity
$$\dbinom{n}{1}\dbinom{2n-1}{n-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\dbinom{n}{k}^2$$

I want to modify the LHS such that:

(a) $$\dbinom{2n}{1}\dbinom{2n-1}{n-1} $$
(b) $$\dbinom{n}{2}\dbinom{2n-2}{n-2}$$

What would be the RHS be when change (a) and change (b) is applied to the LHS?

Answer (score 2):

Use the coefficient extractor $[x^k]:(1+x)^n = \binom{n}{k} $ thingy.

To prove the first formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{k}^2 &=& [x][y^0] : \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (1+x)^k \frac{(1+y)^n}{y^k} \\
&=& [x][y^0] : \left(1+\frac{1+x}{y} \right)^n (1+y)^n \\
&=& [x][y^n] : \left(1+x+y \right)^n (1+y)^n \\
&=& [y^n] : n \left(1+y \right)^{n-1} (1+y)^n \\
&=& [y^n] : n \left(1+y \right)^{2n-1} =n \binom{2n-1}{n}.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Part $a)$ can be done by just multipling by $2$.

Part $b)$ can be done in a similar manner
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{k}{2} \binom{n}{k}^2 &=& [x^2][y^0] : \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (1+x)^k \frac{(1+y)^n}{y^k} \\
&=& [x^2][y^0] : \left(1+\frac{1+x}{y} \right)^n (1+y)^n \\
&=& [x^2][y^n] : \left(1+x+y \right)^n (1+y)^n \\
&=& [y^n] : \binom{n}{2} \left(1+y \right)^{n-2} (1+y)^n \\
&=& [y^n] : \binom{n}{2} \left(1+y \right)^{2n-2} =\binom{n}{2} \binom{2n-2}{n}.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}